# if page 404 error occurs showing an alert or an image instead of error page

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-status-code-404

If am Requesting a file which not found in the directory am getting error status code as 404,instead of showing 404 error page, i just want to keep some text in a div /an alert /showing an image

```
<script>
  $.ajax({ cache: false,
            url: "basic1.css",
            data: { },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#id').html(data);
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                if(xhr.status==404) {
                    //alert(thrownError);
                    alert("the requested page not found");
                }
                           }
        });
     </script>
```

In the above code i want to get an alert instead of error page , and its  directly displaying the error(404) object not found page.

How can i restrict showing the 404 error page ?

Comment: put "/" in  url i.e url: "/basic1.css" and then try your code , other wise it will always goes to success  whether page is there or not. Putting "/" makes correct url."/" represent root.

Comment: I'm not saying where file is , but I saying your url should start with "/" like "/css/basic.css" or "/basic.css" something like that. If you  write this you will get correct error code i.e 404 if path is wrong

Comment: Even after replacing the(url) url: "/basic1.css" its showing the 404 page

Comment: Your code work fine for me. See Demo http://jsfiddle.net/sjnilan/Sdqvv/

Comment: Sorry new to jsfiddle and am not able to see the alert after clicking on RUN,can i know why its not working for me?

Answer (score -2):

Please insert the following code in the error handler

```
<script>
      $.ajax({ cache: false,
                url: "basic1.css",
                data: { },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#id').html(data);
                },
                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                   if(jqXHR.status == 404 || thrownError == 'Not Found') {
                       $('#id').html("<img src='imagelink-here'/>"); // If you want to show an image
                       $('#id').html("Sorry, the page is not found"); // if you need text
                    }
                               }
            });
         </script>
```

Also please make sure the base url for the ajax request is proper.

As per the above code, the ajax request is made to the following URL

```
http://domain.com/basic1.css
```

So make sure to add proper base url and path.

Comment: ever after placing the absolute path of a file its showing the 404 page

Comment: Please check the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/Sdqvv/2/) , The ajax method is working fine